# preact cli project's HMR not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I setup a preact project using preact-cli and made some changes to it. I am using .jsx files for view and JSS for styling. I am also using preact-material-components.

When I first created the project, HMR was working. But after writing some code I realised that HMR is not working. I don't know when it went wrong. Please suggest solution. In my chrome debugger tool I can see this line:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
abstract-xhr.js:131 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1508765305608".
```

But any change is not reflected in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by our Webpack 3 upgrade.  If you update to the latest version (2.0.2), it should be working once again.

Comment: Yes, update to preact-cli 2.0.2 using `npm i -D preact-cli@latest`

Comment: The watcher is working perfectly now but its reloading the whole browser instead of injecting the module HMR way.